# DELL PERC status needs attention

Tags: dell-perc

if anyone is familiar with Dell PowerEdge Raid Controllers (PERC) that are in servers,

I have a PERC H740P that when you go F2 into the BIOS then navigate to the PERC device it says `STATUS: needs attention`.

does anyone know how to figure out what exactly needs attention?  Because I have `cleared configuration` and have tried to `clear` everything yet the thing always seems to say needs attention.  Can someone tell me what might be causing this?  I've cycled power, held the power button down on the server when power has been disconnected, and have created new virtual disks and everything works fine it just always says needs attention.

Answer (score 1):

Similar situation with an H730P in an R730.
I believe that any issue with a virtual drive (i.e. degraded, initializing, rebuild, etc.) will cause this. In my case, the cause was a rebuild in progress for a drive in a raid set. As soon as the rebuild completed the controller status returned to optimal.

Comment: thanks.  I believe they have a bug in their PERC firmware.  I have one disk, forced to be RAID0, so there is no rebuild possible in my case.  I received a firmware update package and used it, it corrected this issue on some servers **but not all**.  I've since sort of given up on it.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the internal battery for the controller is not fully charged or has not completed a full charging cycle, you can check the logs for erros using iDRAC or Dell OpenManage

Comment: it is brand new equipment,and the main screen shows battery 100% and optimal.  There is nothing shown in their screen that indicates what could be a potential problem, it simply says on the main page of the PERC screen *needs attention*.  And there was no errors in any logs that i could find.